# Deleting table cell populated with Dictionary (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add functionality so the user can delete a table cell. However, this table cell is populated using a dictionary so I'm getting an error message: "cannot invoke 'removeAtIndex' with an argument list of type {index: Int)

Here's my code:

```
var titles = [Int: String]()


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        titles.removeAtIndex(index: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary, and is the `Int` actually just an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `removeValueForKey` method, because you use `Int` as keys. The

An you need to add `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` method calls as well to perform the animations.

See the code below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        table.beginUpdates()

        titles.removeValueForKey(index: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

        table.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Note: in such a case, consider using Array instead of Dictionary? You don't actually need dictionary since it will be indexed from row 0 to row count-1, right?

Comment: Well I'm using a dictionary because I'm retrieving the items from Parse and the dictionary ensures they return in the correct order.